# For loop to select specific id and change them style - js

Tags: javascript

I have 10 blocks of this html code:

```
        <a href="#"class="box-wd" id="wd-1" onClick="myFunction()">
            <div class="description" id="des-1">
            </div>
        </a>
```

Each of them with different id. When I click on the first box I would like that its child who belong to the class "description" changes opacity.

I have tried to build this function:

```
            function myFunction() {
                var list_des = document.getElementByClassName('description');
                for(i=0;i<list_des;i++){
                    $('this').css('opacity','1');
                }i++;
            }
```

In the console the error I get is:
document.getElementByClassName is not a function

What should I write to correct this function? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to use querySelectorAll function. It has more flexibility and power.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the name of the function. ans 's' is missing (elements in plural):

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

You should also remove the i++ outside the loop.